# regular expressions for timestamps

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a regex for a timestamp which could be formatted like this

`2011-12-31T23:00:00.000+01:00`

My closest solution I can think of is:

`/^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T:(\d\d):(\d\d).(\d{3})+(\d\d):(\d\d)$/`

But that doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions on where I went wrong? (I'm using this in php preg_match() )

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have `T:` in your regex, yet no `T:` in your timestamp. And you didn't escape out the `+`.

Actually, between the `T` and `:` in your regex, put `(\d\d)`:

```
/^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)\.(\d{3})\+(\d\d):(\d\d)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3}\+\d{2}\:\d{2}$/
```

Comment: Presumably the questioner is trying to capture, else they wouldn't have put parentheses around everything. Further, you don't need to escape every character like `-` or `:`.